# How to show vertical middle advertisement (Window height 50%) in dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to achieve the vertical middle advertisement between the dynamic content (Content including with images and tables). I have to incorporate some tricky placements for this advertisement.

(Note: Its fully responsive layout. so height and width will differ depends on devices)

1. If Div content height fit on the windows height (without vertical scroll), the advertisement will seen vertical middle.
2. If Div Content height exceed the windows height (with vertical scroll), the advertisement will seen vertical middle.
3. If Div content height less than windows height (without vertical scroll, less than 5 lines), the advertisement will seen end of the content

Refer sample content below:-

```
<div id="outer">
  <img style="float:left; margin-right:10px;" src="cow.jpg"> Location 1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
  <table style="border: solid 1px #ccc; margin-bottom:10px; width:100%">
    <tr>
      <td style="border-right: solid 1px #ccc;border-bottom: solid 1px #ccc; padding:10px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</td>
      <td style="border-bottom: solid 1px #ccc;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="border-right: solid 1px #ccc;border-bottom: solid 1px #ccc;padding:10px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</td>
      <td style="border-bottom: solid 1px #ccc;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="border-right: solid 1px #ccc;padding:10px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</td>
      <td >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  Location 2.  Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.      
</div>
```

[image] [image]
Appreciate your inputs on how to resolve this???

Comment: for the moment, do you able to create the css to make the contents vertically aligned?

Comment: I need that advertisement without overlap on the content.
JsFiddle:- http://jsfiddle.net/gsk/nh463q4g/8/

Answer (score 1):

You can start finding a way to do this using `$(window).height()` and `$(document).height()` to determinate if your content is taller than the window, and then, position your ad' at the right top position using position().top.

```
var windowHeight = $(window).height();
var pageHeight = $("body").height();
var adHeight = $("#middle").height();
var scrollPos = $("body").scrollTop();

if ((pageHeight+adHeight)>windowHeight){
    $("article div p").each(function(){
        var middleScreen = (windowHeight/2)+scrollPos;
        if($(this).position().top>middleScreen){
            $("#middle").prependTo($(this));
            return false;
        }    
    });
}else{
    $("#middle").appendTo($("article div p:last-child"));
}
```

Please find a [Live Exemple](http://jsfiddle.net/t3zxpphz/2/) (Note that I haven't done it to work on resize, so you'll have to "Run" the fiddle after resizing your window.)

---

First, I store browser, document, ad' heights, and scroll position. Scroll position will be used after a refresh on a scrolled page.

```
var windowHeight = $(window).height();
var pageHeight = $("body").height();
var adHeight = $("#middle").height();
var scrollPos = $("body").scrollTop();
```

Then, I check if my content height (including the ad') is bigger than my browser height. I run through all `P` in within the `<article>` tag, and check if its position is greater than half the browser height (so, >50% top), and as soon as the `P` tag is great, I stop the `each()` loop and insert the ad' before this `P` :

```
if ((pageHeight+adHeight)>windowHeight){
    $("article div p").each(function(){
        var middleScreen = (windowHeight/2)+scrollPos;
        if($(this).position().top>middleScreen){
            $("#middle").prependTo($(this));
            return false;
        }    
    });
}
```

And finally, if content is smaller, I insert the ad' after the last `P` :

```
}else{
    $("#middle").appendTo($("article div p:last-child"));
}
```